# Make octal numbers into real number in c++

Tags: c++

i want 010 + 10 = 20 in c++. I know that 010 is a octal number , which is equal to 8, but is there anyway to show that inputing 010 + 10 = 20 (without having to get rid of the 0 in front of 10.)

i need to put the 0 in front of the 10, there got to be a way to show it as a real number.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Maybe you want to change `010` to `012`.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to put `0` in front of the `10`?

You are writing down a *numeric value*, and not a string that needs conversion. If you want to write down the value `10` (base 10), you can do that in base ten, being the default, by just typing `10`, in base `8` (octal) by typing `012`, in base `16` (hex) by typing `0xA`.

If you need to convert a string to integer, then (using `c++11`), you can do:

```
int myval = std::stoi("010");
```

Which will truncate any leading 0s, and the result is `myval = 10`.

---

The default base for `std::stoi` is `10`, but you can specify a different base with the third parameter.

```
int myval = std::stoi("010", 0, 8); // Base 8, myval = 8 now.
int myval = std::stoi("010", 0, 16); // Base 16, myval = 16 now.
```

Comment: i need to add two times together, example the time1 0222(2.22am) and time 2 1220(12.20am) 

time1 + time2 = 1442(2.42pm)